Transistor Testing Circuit
In my previous posts I started way above my knowledge level so I decided to go to the basics. I googled online and came across this transistor testing circuit. I was hoping someone could tell me if I'm reading this right
I originally found this image on a reddit post that explained how it functioned but wanted to see if my own understanding was operated properly.

Cap charges through 330k resistor

Once cap charges enough it turns on NPN which also turns on PNP

Because of the higher current on the right side of the cap, it provides positive feedback to the NPN and causes both to turn on more.

Once the PNP is fully saturated, most of the current is flowing through that portion of the circuit.

As the positive feedback begins to taper off, the current on the NPN slowly drops causing it to slowly turn off, which also forces the PNP to slowly shut off.

Due to this happening, the cap starts to discharge through the 22R

Now that the cap is discharging through the 22R, the cap is pulling current away from the NPN and the 330k is limiting its "speed" so the NPN continues to shut off.

Once the cap has discharged enough in one direction it stops all current to the NPN until it's charged enough to start it up again.


Cycle repeats.
Image source:
https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/1819lio/help_understanding_role_of_capacitor_in/
Is this the right logic?

Someone explained to me the capacitor decouple the two transistors and allows the PNP to only be affected by the collector of the NPN but I'm not understanding how that works.

This isn’t a good circuit because putting led to pnp emitter doesn’t allow capacitor to charge more than about 300mV. It should work but it’s a total mess.

Point 6 is not exact. During positive feedback the capacitor has already been discharged a bit. After PNP off the charge is close to the initial value.

@DNEME The only complaint I have about your description (or Hacktastical's acceptance of it) is that it is the NPN base current that causes the capacitor's high, early discharge rate. Once the capacitor's voltage drops enough, then there's no longer enough current feeding the PNP and it is only then, later in that discharge cycle, where a 2nd phase of the feedback system allows the 22 Ohm resistor to start hauling down on the (-) end of the capacitor. But the earlier NPN base draw isn't an unimportant factor.

If this is a transistor tester, then where is the slot where the transistor goes?

The only thing this tests is that it is NPN and has hFE > 5. Above that it makes no visible difference,  So it only checks the orientation and that it is any NPN.  Is that kind of a low bar now?

Keep in mind this is more of a fundamental example rather than a fool proof way to test a transistor. Im still learning solid state so I was just checking to make sure my logic was on track.

@DNEME You missed something important. But got most of it.

The circuit works basically as you describe. The problem is that the LED 'on' time is quite short, making it hard to see.
Here's a sim that shows that (simulate it here):

I also think the cap should be non-polarized, as its voltage swings both positive and negative (about +/- 400mV). The sim works because the cap is set to a max reverse voltage of 1V; if it's set to zero it fails.

Tested it with non-polarized cap. and it is around the same short delay could be a resistor (330k)

Yes, it works the same with an NP cap. There's some things that can be done to make the blink a bit more apparent, but it does work.

I measured 0.1% d.f. with 1.5Hz on Falstad which is pretty dim with 30 mA peak and has no sensitivity with hFE, fT, Roe and Cce, Ccb and most other variables.  I wonder what the test criteria show be? (any NPN in the correct orientation?)

I use the android app EveryCircuit and when I attempted to simulate this it just locked up in the on position so I have my transistor variables wrong somewhere.
